# rotation is independent of setting layout and so views don't fit in layout after rotation in android

Tags: android, animation, android-relativelayout

I have a layout in which there is an `imageView` and a `textView` with a single character. In some situations, this layout is rotated but the problem is that since the rotation is independent of setting the layout, in cases, the `textView` does not fit in the layout properly. how can I fix this problem?

Here's The code:

```
RelativeLayout arrowLayout = new RelativeLayout(myLayout.getContext());
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams arrowLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(metrics.heightPixels / 8, metrics.heightPixels / 8);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams tagLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

float x1 = origin.getLeft() + origin.getWidth() / 2, y1 = origin.getTop() + origin.getHeight() / 2;
int stateSize = origin.getWidth();
layoutParams.leftMargin = (int) (x1 - stateSize * 3 / 2);
layoutParams.topMargin = (int) (y1 - stateSize / 2);

tagLayoutParams.setMargins(metrics.heightPixels / 8, 0, 0, 0);
setPivotY(0);
setPivotX(0);
tag.animate().rotation(180f).setDuration(0).start();

if (x1 < metrics.widthPixels * 3 / 20) {
    if (metrics.heightPixels - y1 < metrics.widthPixels * 3 / 20) {
        arrowLayout.animate().rotation(270f).translationX(stateSize).translationY(-stateSize).setDuration(0).start();
        tag.animate().rotation(90f).setDuration(0).start();
    }
    else {
        arrowLayout.animate().rotation(90f).translationX(stateSize).translationY(stateSize).setDuration(0).start();
        tag.animate().rotation(-90f).setDuration(0).start();
    }
}
else {
    arrowLayout.animate().rotation(180f).setDuration(0).start();
}

arrowLayout.addView(tag, tagLayoutParams);
arrowLayout.addView(this, arrowLayoutParams);
myLayout.addView(arrowLayout, layoutParams);
```

where `this` is the `imageView` and `tag` is the `textView`.

[image]

Comment: not sure i understand the problem, but, would it help to define that layout file two different ways (one for landscape and one for portrait orientation) in two different resource folders: layout-land and layout-port ?

Comment: @albertcbraun it is not the matter of rotating the screen. It is the matter of `animate().rotate()` which means that I have to change the direction of an imageView and a textView due to some user interactions.

Comment: ah. ok. thank you for helping me to better understand the problem. the text i see in the image above has 6 characters (a + b)*  (not counting the spaces), but the description says there's a textview with a "single character", and so i'm confused about that too.

Comment: @albertcbraun the textView below the arrow is the problem. As you see, it is the single character "a" but it is not complete; meaning that the bottom of the character is not visible

Comment: What exactly is your need i couldn't understand can you make it little bit clear

Comment: @GT what I need is to have the full character shown under the arrow. The place is just ok when it is horizontal but when I rotate it to vertical, the character is not fully visible.

Answer (score -1):

Try removing this line: `tagLayoutParams.setMargins(metrics.heightPixels / 8, 0, 0, 0);`

Or be sure that the "metrics.heightPixels" is not so large.